# How to create Tab within tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabhost

How can i create a design like below:

```
  ----------------------
 |Tab 1 | Tab 2 | tab 3 |
 -----------------------
 | Sub tab 1 | Sub tab 2|
  ----------------------
```

Below is the approach that i am following, but i dont know how to create second level tab:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
   android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="top"
   android:background="#33b5e5"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:paddingTop="4dp"
   android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a TabHost in the Fragment whose content needs the sub-tabs. Or you can change your application's navigation to not have stacked tabs (which looks ugly)

Comment: but tabhost(Tab Activity) has been depreciated if i am not wrong.

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated. TabHost is not. There is also FragmentTabHost if you are using Fragments.

Comment: could you please give some example links.